# How do I change the OS X updater App store user?

Tags: macos, apple-id

When I go to do App store system updates it prompts for the Apple ID, but not mine...  It's asking for a former employee.  For now I can reset their password (as their old e-mail can be redirected) and continue to use that account.  However, long term I'd like to switch that over to a different Apple ID so that the ex-employee Apple ID can be entirely shut down.  How do I go about changing the Apple ID used for system updates?

Comment: Your IT department needs to get involved if the computer is managed in some way. Ideally, the computer should be wiped clean, macOS reinstalled, and your Apple ID used for updates.

Comment: I am IT for the company and have full administrator access to this machine.  :-)  This machine is AD joined so all our accounts are separate on there.  It works great except for somehow the system updates are locked down to specific Apple ID.  I just figured there was some way to reset that without the labor of doing a full wipe/reinstall.